# renaming a file in /system/lib is not working

Tags: android, local-storage, root, adb

I'm about to rename a file inside /system/lib folder, however everytime i run the code below on Android, the file name still the same and nothing change.

This code works on local storage file. The phone I used is Note3 and it's rooted. I try to rename this file using app called ES file manager app and I was able to do so. But not using this code.

`String shellCommand = "su mv /system/lib/libft2.so /system/lib/libft2.sok";`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCommand);`

Could you help me what could be wrong here or something needs to be improved/add?

Comment: So what happens when you adb shell in and run the command? Do you check the error stream from the returned `Process`?

Comment: I got this message upon running on terminal "Read-only file system". The file i was working has -rw-rw-rw- permission

Comment: you'll need to do on your local terminal prompt : `adb root` , `adb remount` , `adb shell` - then your command..

Comment: Tried to remount the system, using this "mount -o ro,remount /system", but still the error message. "Read-only file system" :/

Comment: my mistake this i entered "ro" instead of "rw". I finally renamed the file

Comment: I'll try using android code.

Comment: Im stuck here

`String execute = "su && mount -o rw, remount /system && mv /system/lib/libGLESv3.so /system/lib/libGLESv3.sok";  `

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCommand);`

Didn't get error message, but the file name still the same.